Why the hyperbolic Laplacian?
In the theory of automorphic forms there is the weight $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ Laplacian
\begin{align*}
\Delta_k:=-y^2 \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right)+iky\frac{\partial}{\partial x}.
\end{align*}
Maass forms are eigenfunctions of this Laplacian, satisfy moderate growth conditions, and satisfy modular transformations $(\varphi|_k \gamma)(z) = \varphi(z)$ for the weight $k$ slash operator, $\gamma\in\Gamma\leq \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. The theory of Maass forms is incredibly rich, encompassing the theory of holomorphic modular forms because these sit at the bottom of the spectrum for the $\Delta_k$ operator. Moreover, as far as I understand, the theory of automorphic representations for $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ amounts to the study of (adelic lifts) of Maass forms, as in Goldfeld and Hundley Section 4.8.
Then there is the theory of the weight $k\in\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$ hyperbolic Laplacian (Bringmann Folsom Ono Rolen Chapter 4)
\begin{align*}
\tilde\Delta_k:=-y^2 \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right)+iky\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right).
\end{align*}
Functions which are annihilated by this differential operator and satisfy modular transformations as well as appropriate growth conditions are called weak harmonic Maass forms. The space of weak harmonic Maass forms also includes the holomorphic modular forms because holomorphic functions are annihilated by the hyperbolic Laplacian. The theory of weak harmonic Maass forms also has Hecke and raising and lowering operators, among other seeming similarities.
Do we introduce the hyperbolic Laplacian simply because it's a slight tweak on the spaces of functions we can consider, or because it's essential when considering half-integral weights, or for some other reason? Does the overlap for the theories consist of only the holomorphic modular forms? In a word, is there a natural reason to also consider the hyperbolic Laplacian and not just the weight $k$ Laplacian?

These are the same operator. You get one from the other by replacing $f(z)$ with $y^kf(z)$.
